# Can I access the variable in NPAPI like the structure in C language?

Tags: npapi

As the title,

Can I access the variable in NPAPI like the structure in C language?

for example

Here is a variable called ErrorCode

Can I get and set the varibale like this style in my web

```
var obj = document.getElementById("pluginObj");
function testui(){
    alert(obj.ErrorCode);
}
```

3Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if it is a Property.

(To provide a Property you need to implement [HasProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_HasProperty), [GetProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_GetProperty), and [SetProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_SetProperty))